# How to Display CurrentColor with Opacity in Rgba SASS/SCSS?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, tailwind-css

is there anymethod which I can Display **CurrentColor** with **Opacity** in **Rgba** from **Colors** List using **SASS/SCSS**?

**My Colors List :**

```
$colors: (
  "transparent": (
     hex: transparent,
     rgb: (0, 0, 0)
  ),
  "current": (
     hex: currentColor,
     rgb: (255, 255, 255)
  ),
  "white": (
    hex: #FFFFFF,
    rgb: (255, 255, 255)
  ),
  "black": (
    hex: #000000,
    rgb: (0, 0, 0)
  ),
) !default;
```

**The result that I expected after compiling to CSS :**

```
.color-transparent {
  --color-opacity: 0;
  --color-var: transparent;
  color: (var(--color-var), rgba(0, 0, 0, var(--color-opacity)));
}

.color-current {
  --color-opacity: 0;
  --color-var: currentColor;
  color: (var(--color-var), rgba(255, 255, 255, var(--color-opacity)));
}

.color-white {
  --color-opacity: 0;
  --color-var: #FFFFFF;
  color: (var(--color-var), rgba(255, 255, 255, var(--color-opacity)));
}

.color-black {
  --color-opacity: 0;
  --color-var: #000000;
  color: (var(--color-var), rgba(0, 0, 0, var(--color-opacity)));
}
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: you can check this [question to know more about what I want to do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64389233/each-loop-scss-sass-display-gradient-color-palette-list-with-hex-and-rgb-form)

Comment: I've added an answer. On a side note, going forward, like @Arkellys said, you are going to have to start showing that you've tried something. So far, all the questions you've asked, show that you have not even attempted to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you do it:

```
$colors: (
  "transparent": (
     hex: transparent,
     rgb: (0, 0, 0)
  ),
  "current": (
     hex: currentColor,
     rgb: (255, 255, 255)
  ),
  "white": (
    hex: #FFFFFF,
    rgb: (255, 255, 255)
  ),
  "black": (
    hex: #000000,
    rgb: (0, 0, 0)
  ),
) !default;


// $COLOR = KEY, $VALUE = VALUE, $COLORS = MAP
@each $color, $values in $colors {
    .color-#{$color} {
        --color-opacity: 0;
        @each $value, $subvalue in $values {
            @if $value == 'hex' {
        --color-var: #{$subvalue};
            } @else {
                color: ( var(--color-var), rgba( #{$subvalue}, var(--color-opacity)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### CSS OUTPUT

```
.color-transparent {
  --color-opacity: 0;
  --color-var: transparent;
  color: var(--color-var), rgba(0, 0, 0, var(--color-opacity));
}

.color-current {
  --color-opacity: 0;
  --color-var: currentColor;
  color: var(--color-var), rgba(255, 255, 255, var(--color-opacity));
}

.color-white {
  --color-opacity: 0;
  --color-var: #FFFFFF;
  color: var(--color-var), rgba(255, 255, 255, var(--color-opacity));
}

.color-black {
  --color-opacity: 0;
  --color-var: #000000;
  color: var(--color-var), rgba(0, 0, 0, var(--color-opacity));
}
```

Comment: it work when I tested the code in **sassmeister** but in my local developement and **codepen** show me an error **$color: "0, 0, 0" is not a color for `rgba'** [Check this](https://codepen.io/themes4all/pen/xxOVXQW)